# Cloud Storage ACL App Engine Confusion

Tags: google-app-engine, cloud, google-cloud-storage

I used gsutil to change my bucket with the following command...

```
python gsutil defacl ch -g AllUsers:R gs://{MY_BUCKET_NAME}
```

This was intentional, as I'm trying to have the uploads be publicly visible.

I'm using the App Engine cloud storage client library. Running the sample code as is results in this:

I go to the bucket in cloud storage ACL console and I can see the checkbox for "shared publicly" is checked by default (sounds like my ACL is working)...

However, whenever I use an incognito window to navigate to the canonical cloud storage url for the uploaded object...it prompts me for the Sign in Page...

Sample python code I'm using...
(Also...the x-goog-acl being commented out is from before I changed the default ACL via gsutil

```
gcs_file = gcs.open(filename,
                            'w',
                            content_type='text/plain',
                            options={'x-goog-meta-foo': 'foo',
                                     'x-goog-meta-bar': 'bar'},
#                                     'x-goog-acl': 'public-read'},
                            retry_params=write_retry_params)
```

Comment: OK Nevermind...it ended up being something super lame...I guess storage.cloud.google.com will always ask the user to sign in...whereas storage.googleapis.com will respect public-read ACL

Comment: @mimber - mind posting that you were using the wrong domain as an answer, for posterity's sake?